# Redirect user based on custom metadata, wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added some custom metadata to wordpress per user and would like to redirect each user after login based on this custom metadata.

For instance i have a page called foo and another called bar. User one has a custom key (acCustomerName) in the metadata stating foo. And the other user has bar in his.

Depending on whats inside that field I would like to redirect the first user to http://example.tld/foo and the other to http://example.tld/bar.

I am able to retrieve this information perfectly fine and echo it out directly to test the function but are not able to retrieve that information inside the sencond function named forward_user and would like to know why.

Right now the user is redirected only to http://example.tld only. So it seems like the function does not get the $kundtyp string.

```
function kundtyp($Uuser) {
        $key = 'acCustomerName';
        $single = true;
        return get_user_meta( $Uuser, $key, $single );
}


function forward_user( $redirect, $user ) {
        $kundtyp = kundtyp($user);
        $redirect_page_id = url_to_postid( $redirect );
        $checkout_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
        if( $redirect_page_id == $checkout_page_id ) {
                return $redirect;
        }
        return site_url( kundtyp( get_current_user_id() ) );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'forward_user', 1100, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code, you have to pass the ID of the user object to get_user_meta data function.  You were passing the WP_User object to your function.  I don't think you can use function get_current_user_id() because the global wp_user object has not been set yet.  I checked it and it always returns 0 as the value.  This would explain why they provide the $user variable in the filter.

```
function kundtyp($Uuser) {
    $key = 'acCustomerName';
    $single = true;
    return get_user_meta( $Uuser->ID, $key, $single );
}


function forward_user( $redirect, $user ) {
    $kundtyp = kundtyp($user);
    $redirect_page_id = url_to_postid( $redirect );
    $checkout_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
    if( $redirect_page_id == $checkout_page_id ) {
            return $redirect;
    }

    return site_url( kundtyp( $user ) );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'forward_user', 1100, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me alot.

Comment: @hrdy you're welcome.  Not 100% sure why get_current_user_id() is returning 0 though... Need to do some research :)